# Wordpress echoing Array word

Tags: php, wordpress

When I add this code into my template, i see all of the thumbnails and my links are generating correctly. The only problem is that I'm also seeing the word "Array" in the page next to each thumbnail. Where is this array word coming from and how do i get rid of it?  Seems very bizarre.

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_parent' => $post->ID
);

$attachments = get_posts($args);
if ($attachments) {
    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {

        //wp_get_attachment_thumb_url($post->ID);
        /* $img_attr_full = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full');
          $img_attr_thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'thumbnail'); */

        echo '<li type="1">';
        echo '<a id="' . $post->ID . '" href="' . $img_attr_full[0] . '" class="gallery ' . $media_type . ' ' . $media . '" data-media-type="' . $media . '" target="_blank" rel="gallery">';
        echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment->ID, 'thumbnail');
        echo '</a></li>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any more code?  You would see "Array" if you attempted to echo a value that was an array instead of a string.  The code you have there doesn't look like it should cause that problem.

Comment: Could you post a part of the source code generated to see where exactly is the Array word appearing?

Comment: It adds the word array right after the closing </li> tag in the list.

    ‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·‌¶‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·Array‌→‌→‌→‌·‌·‌¶‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·‌·

Thats what it looks like in firebug.

to output the code above i just echo it out.

    <?php 
 /* Let's output all of the thumbnails for everything except the videos */
        echo $attachments; 
    ?>

Comment: what do you mean to output the code above?
if you're doing something like
<ul>
<?php echo $attachments;?></ul>
then there's your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src): the implementation of `wp_get_attachment_image_src` which you are using to fetch the URL for the `a` element returns an array.

EDIT: `echo $attachments;` will print out `Array`. If you remove that you should get better results. In addition, provide a coherent code sample that reflects what is actually in use and producing the error, or you'll cause confusion.

Comment: and he's calling the index 0 which corresponds with the url, the weird thing is he has the assignement of $img_attr_full commented =S

Comment: ok, but why is it outputting the word "array" on the page? And how can i get rid of it. its messing the page up.

Comment: yeah i had that line commented, i have trying different things to find the cause. I've since uncommented that line and it still does the same thing. :(

Comment: then where's getting the $img_attr_full[0] from to create the url?

Comment: pretend like it wasn't commented out. i was playing with the code and forgot to uncomment it out before i posted. my apologies.

Comment: bingo! femi that was it. I think i had seen it in a code sample that i found so i thought it was needed. apparently not. sorry about that gang, thanks for your help.  I've been staring at these pages too long.